# what format is most reliable for saving a history file from an application?

Tags: vb.net

Good Afternoon,

I am in the process of developing in vb.net a simple “cheque printing” application which will allow users to fill in a few text boxes with the values that will be printed on  a cheque.

When they hit the print button, the values will be sent to the printer, but I also want the values they input in the text boxes saved to a file, so like a history file of all the cheques that were created.

I am thinking to use either an access database or an excel spreadsheet as my history file, but I am not quite sure on which would be best.

Please note that in my environment storing this information in a SQL database is not an option and also this file will most likely be stored/accessed from the network.

The history file needs to be:

1.Stable (cannot corrupt easy)

2.Reliable

3.Easily exportable in case we need to export the information to one of our in-house systems.

4.editable from the application I am developing

Kindly advise,
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML. Save the data to `DataTable` object and then use the `.WriteXML` method to save it as an xml file. I'd advise creating a strongly-typed `DataTable` class for this, so that the XML can be exported with a reliable schema and imported easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using different fonts, you could use a .rtf (rich text format) which will save the format of the text that you send to print... it is a universal file format, you can open it with open office, ms office, or any office suite you have...

Answer (score 0):

Access will be best choice,

it's relational database and can make a form from this file to do what are you looking for without VB or any code.

Also you can access this file from network.

for more detail about setting for this file go to this link
http://goo.gl/bOfGp6

and you will find more options complete your work.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a MySQL server. It's free.
XML is also good, but I hate sharing folders...

Comment: It clearly said in the question that SQL DB is not an option.

Comment: First of all, let him decide that. Maybe he was referring to MS SQL Server which is very expansive - not an option. Second, he's not an "it", he is a "he". Thanks for your encouraging vote for my first answer.